# Code Score Cards

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm trying out a new type of review, which includes a score card at the top *in addition to the rest of the review* to summarize how the code shapes up.  I would like to standardize the scores within the card and improve it.

Here's what it currently looks like:

> ## Code Score
>
> 1. **Design**: n/a
> 2. **Readability & Maintainability**: n/a
> 3. **Functionality**: n/a
> 4. **Performance**: n/a
> 5. **Security**: n/a
> 6. **Test coverage**: n/a

Any suggestions on improving them?

Comment: If you are teaching CS students, an explanation of your reasoning for these categories may be helpful. If you are reviewing the work of other professionals this is useless. Just do standard code reviews.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### How does a score card actually help the OP?

Telling them their code sucks, without explaining how to improve it, is no benefit to anybody.

Telling them how to improve it, by definition, involves explaining why it's not so good at the moment. So why have the score if you're just going to tell them in your review anyway.

Additionally, code reviews are inherently subjective. You can objectively say if code follows certain standards and best practices, but then you fall into the trap of optimising for metrics you can objectively measure, as opposed to the things that are actually important (In general or in the specific context of the code).

IMO, a score card is going to be kinda feel-good but incredibly subjective and will not add anything useful to a review. It may even hurt by implying a level of objectivity and certainty that **never** exists in code.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that this is a very bad idea.

We are already subject to users that are giving code only reviews, which are not reviews at all and don't belong on Code Review, if we start doing this score card type of deal I am afraid that new users will start posting just the score cards and not posting an actual review.

Score Cards are not needed, there is enough gaming of the SE system that goes on around here already.

We have enough things to flag and edit around here.

There is plenty to review in the code when a good question or code base is posted.